# Service to Service call and Graph APi

Tags: office365api, azure-ad-graph-api

I registered a web API https://dev.office.com/app-registration. I kept sign URL 
localhost:8000 and RedirectURI as localhost:8000.

After this, I created a console application to access the graph API. Here is the code. But it doesnt work. I get the error "access denied".

Am I missing anything here?

One more thing, I checked the access_token and I dont see any user information there. 
            string clientId = "<>";
            string clientsecret = "<>";
            string tenant = "my.com";

```
        var authUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant + "/oauth2/token";  
        var RESOURCE_URL = "https://graph.microsoft.com";

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authUri);
        var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId: clientId, clientSecret: clientsecret);
            var result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(RESOURCE_URL, credential).Result;
            Console.WriteLine(result.AccessToken.ToString());

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "bearer " + result.AccessToken);
        var httpContent = new StringContent(content, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"), "application/json");
        var response = client.GetAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/ankushb/calendar/events").Result;
    //    var response = client.PostAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups", httpContent).Result;
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic authentication flow for OAuth2 that Azure AD use.

First is [authorization code grant flow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx) which used to access to web APIs by native clients and websites.In this flow, the user delegates access to a client application.

Second is [Client Credentials grant flow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx) which permits a web service (a confidential client) to use its own credentials to authenticate when calling another web service, instead of impersonating a user. In this scenario, the client is typically a middle-tier web service, a daemon service, or web site.

The code above is using the **Client Credentials grant flow**, that's the reason there is no user information.

In your scenario, you should register an native app(**console application is not confidential clients which should not use the secret to request for the token** ) and use the **authorization code grant flow** to enable users sign-in with their account. And to use this flow in a console application, we need to prompt a web dialog navigate to the login-in page and get the auth code to request for the access token.

Here is an sample to authenticate the app with authorization code grant flow:

```
 var oauth = new OauthConfiguration
        {
            Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com",
            Tenant = "common",
            ClientId = "{clientId}",
            RedirectURI = "{redirectURL}",
            Secret = ""
        };
        var tokenResponse = new OAuth2.OauthWebAuthHelper(oauth).AcquireTokenWithResource("https://graph.microsoft.com");
        var accessToken = tokenResponse.GetValue("access_token").Value<string>();
        var refreshToken = tokenResponse.GetValue("refresh_token").Value<string>();


namespace OAuth2
{
public class OauthWebAuthHelper
{
    public enum Version
    {
        V1 = 1,
        V2 = 2
    }

    private OauthConfiguration _configuration;

    private const string OAUTH2_AUTHORIZE_V1_SUFFIX = @"oauth2/";

    private const string OAUTH2_AUTHORIZE_V2_SUFFIX = @"oauth2/v2.0";

    private string _authorizeSuffix;

    public OauthWebAuthHelper(OauthConfiguration configuration, Version version = Version.V1)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;

        switch (version)
        {
            case Version.V1: _authorizeSuffix = OAUTH2_AUTHORIZE_V1_SUFFIX; break;

            case Version.V2: _authorizeSuffix = OAUTH2_AUTHORIZE_V2_SUFFIX; break;
        }
    }

    public void LogOut()
    {
        var dialog = new WebBrowserDialog();

        dialog.Open(string.Format("{0}/logout", EndPointUrl));
    }

    protected string EndPointUrl
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", _configuration.Authority, _configuration.Tenant, _authorizeSuffix);
        }
    }


    public JObject GetAuthorizationCode()
    {
        JObject response = new JObject();

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "response_type", "code" },
                { "client_id", _configuration.ClientId },
                { "redirect_uri", _configuration.RedirectURI },
                { "prompt", "login"}
            };

        var requestUrl = string.Format("{0}/authorize?{1}", EndPointUrl, BuildQueryString(parameters));

        var dialog = new WebBrowserDialog();

        dialog.OnNavigated((sender, arg) =>
        {
            if (arg.Url.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith(_configuration.RedirectURI))
            {
                var collection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(arg.Url.Query);

                foreach (var key in collection.AllKeys)
                {
                    response.Add(key, collection[key]);
                }

                dialog.Close();
            }
        });

        dialog.Open(requestUrl);

        return response;
    }


    public JObject GetAuthorizationCode(string scope)
    {
        JObject response = new JObject();

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "response_type", "code" },
                { "client_id", _configuration.ClientId },
                { "redirect_uri", _configuration.RedirectURI },
                { "prompt", "login"},
                { "scope", scope}
            };

        var requestUrl = string.Format("{0}/authorize?{1}", EndPointUrl, BuildQueryString(parameters));

        var dialog = new WebBrowserDialog();

        dialog.OnNavigated((sender, arg) =>
        {
            if (arg.Url.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith(_configuration.RedirectURI))
            {
                var collection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(arg.Url.Query);

                foreach (var key in collection.AllKeys)
                {
                    response.Add(key, collection[key]);
                }

                dialog.Close();
            }
        });

        dialog.Open(requestUrl);

        return response;
    }

    public JObject AcquireTokenWithResource(string resource)
    {
        var codeResponse = GetAuthorizationCode();

        var code = codeResponse.GetValue("code").Value<string>();

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "resource", resource},
                { "client_id", _configuration.ClientId },
                { "code",  code},
                { "grant_type", "authorization_code" },
                { "redirect_uri", _configuration.RedirectURI},
                { "client_secret",_configuration.Secret}
            };

        var client = new HttpClient();

        var content = new StringContent(BuildQueryString(parameters), Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"), "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        var url = string.Format("{0}/token", EndPointUrl);

        var response = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;

        var text = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text) as JObject;
    }


    public JObject RefreshTokenWithResource(string refreshToken)
    {
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "client_id", _configuration.ClientId },
                { "refresh_token",  refreshToken},
                { "grant_type", "refresh_token" }
            };

        var client = new HttpClient();

        var content = new StringContent(BuildQueryString(parameters), Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"), "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        var url = string.Format("{0}/token", EndPointUrl);

        var response = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;

        var text = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text) as JObject;
    }

    public JObject AcquireTokenWithScope(string scope)
    {
        var codeResponse = GetAuthorizationCode(scope);

        var code = codeResponse.GetValue("code").Value<string>();

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "client_id", _configuration.ClientId },
                { "code",  code},
                { "grant_type", "authorization_code" },
                { "redirect_uri", _configuration.RedirectURI},
            };

        var client = new HttpClient();

        var content = new StringContent(BuildQueryString(parameters), Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"), "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        var url = string.Format("{0}/token", EndPointUrl);

        var response = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;

        var text = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text) as JObject;
    }

    private string BuildQueryString(IDictionary<string, string> parameters)
    {
        var list = new List<string>();

        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter.Value))
                list.Add(string.Format("{0}={1}", parameter.Key, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(parameter.Value)));
        }

        return string.Join("&", list);
    }
}

 public class OauthConfiguration
{
    public string Authority { get; set; }

    public string Tenant { get; set; }

    public string ClientId { get; set; }

    public string RedirectURI { get; set; }

    public string Secret { get; set; }
}

 public class WebBrowserDialog
{
    private const int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 400;

    private const int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 500;

    private Form _displayLoginForm;

    private string _title;

    private WebBrowser _browser;

    private WebBrowserNavigatedEventHandler _webBrowserNavigatedEventHandler;

    public WebBrowserDialog()
    {
        _title = "OAuth Basic";

        _browser = new WebBrowser();

        _browser.Width = DEFAULT_WIDTH;

        _browser.Height = DEFAULT_HEIGHT;

        _browser.Navigated += WebBrowserNavigatedEventHandler;

        _displayLoginForm = new Form();

        _displayLoginForm.SuspendLayout();

        _displayLoginForm.Width = DEFAULT_WIDTH;

        _displayLoginForm.Height = DEFAULT_HEIGHT;

        _displayLoginForm.Text = _title;

        _displayLoginForm.Controls.Add(_browser);

        _displayLoginForm.ResumeLayout(false);
    }


    public void OnNavigated(WebBrowserNavigatedEventHandler handler)
    {
        _webBrowserNavigatedEventHandler = handler;
    }

    protected void WebBrowserNavigatedEventHandler(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(_webBrowserNavigatedEventHandler != null)
        {
            _webBrowserNavigatedEventHandler.Invoke(sender, e);
        }
    }

    public void Open(string url)
    {
        _browser.Navigate(url);

        _displayLoginForm.ShowDialog();
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        _displayLoginForm.Close();
    }
}
}
```

And you can get more samples about Microsoft Graph from [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/platform/rest).